# Question about unfamiliar notation regarding P-lim

Tags: probability-theory, notation

I'm attending a finance course which takes knowledge about probability theory as a given (and I'm pretty unfamiliar with probablity theory but until now everything is somewhat understandable for me) and I am unfamiliar with some notation.

The notation I do not comprehend reads as following:

**$\mathbb{P} $-$ \space lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{t \in [0,T]} | (X - C)_t |  = 0 $ where the limit is taken in probability.**

The part most difficult to me is  ''$\mathbb{P} $- lim'', I have never seen this expression before, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: It means that we are talking about [convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) (I think)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maximilian. I still don't really understand what exactly converges in probability here (the probabilty of any supremum being not a constant doesn't make sense to me).

Comment: The supremum of multiple random variables is another random variable

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I still don't get how this new random variable converges to zero, or what this really means (other than, because it's probability is zero, there is no 'final' limit).

Comment: Think about two random variables $X,Y$ first. Then we define $\sup(X,Y)$ pointwise (i.e. if $Z=\sup(X,Y)$ then $Z(\omega)=\sup(X(\omega),Y(\omega))$.) Try to see for example what happens if you take the supremum of two uniform random variables. And the convergence in probability is explained in fair detail in the Wikipedia article

Comment: Thanks again. I guess the wikipedia article is not helping with the part I do not grasp. In the definition there is an $\epsilon$ and it looks 'sequencey-like'. Here, with this notation I do not understand which part converges against which other part (to what extent). e.g if in the brackets || there would be an expression like $X_t-X$, what does that mean exactly? Accoridng to my understanding this means that supremum of $ X_t - X$ would never be reached (in the limit) and therefore has probability 0.

Comment: Maybe this makes it more clear: Let $Z=\sup_{t\in [0,T]} \lvert (X-C)_t\rvert$. **Then $Z$ is a random variable.** (Make sure you understand this). Also, we know that $Z\to0$ in probability

Comment: Ah thanks, the last part is the one I needed (that Z converges to zero (in probability) ).